# Ubuntu 22.10 Audio Skipping, crackling, fuzzy sound

Tags: sound

I just switched to Ubuntu 22.10 and the audio on all sites is crackling, skipping, and sounds fuzzy and low quality. I tried reinstalling and the problem remains. I never had this problem on my laptop that also runs Ubuntu 22.10.

Some other posts with the same issue cite pulseaudio as the problem but my 22.10 system doesn't use pulseaudio.

Comment: No, its Ubuntu 22.10 specific. I switched to lubuntu on my desktop and the problem wasn't present. But if I can get this fixed I'd prefer to be using Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: The problem I'm describing has been reported by other users who fixed it by disabling pulseaudio. Its happening on all of my audio; CDs on rythmbox, youtube, spotify, netflix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by installing PulseEffects and PulseAudio Volume Control. Then I restarted and the problem disappeared.

I don't know why this works but maybe someone else does.